# What is difference between + operator and + function is vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

there is + operator in vhdl to addition operation then why do we need to add  ieee.std_logic_unsigned and in this library there is function for + so why that function is defined if we already have + operator in vhdl?

Comment: Predefined mathematical operations are not provided by default for array types. They are found in specifc packages in library IEEE. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8 Standard synthesis packages, particularly 16.8.5 Packages for arithmetic using bit and standard logic values. In the -2008 revision these packages are part of the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator, like all VHDL operators, also has a functional notation. `a+b` and `"+"(a,b)` are exactly the same. The good aspect of this is that you can overload the VHDL operators to operate on types for which they are not defined by default. Simply define a `"+"` function that takes two arguments of your own type `my_type` and voilà. You can now use `a+b` where `a` and `b` are of type `my_type`.

The `+` operator is not defined by default on types `std_ulogic_vector` or `std_logic_vector`. This is a fact. You can disagree with this but it is the VHDL standard. So, if you want to use it with these types you need to define it one way or another.

The `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` package overloads the arithmetic operators on them. It is **not** a standard package and has **nothing** to do in the standardized `ieee` library. Do **not** use it. Use the standard `ieee.numeric_std`, instead, that declares types `unsigned` and `signed` and overloads the arithmetic operators on them.

Note that, as mentioned by user1155120, VHDL 2008 introduced several new synthesis packages. One of them is `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned` and it does overload the arithmetic operators on type `std_ulogic_vector` considered as unsigned natural integers.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.5 Packages for arithmetic using bit and standard logic values , 16.8.5.1 paragraph 5 (in part): "...Similarly, the NUMERIC_STD_UNSIGNED package provides the same operations as those provided by the NUMERIC_STD package on UNSIGNED operands, but operating on STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR operands interpreted as representing unsigned binary integers."  Converts operand and result times to/from unsigned. In -2008 `subtype STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is (resolved) STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR;`

Comment: can you tell me that when we write a <=  b and c after 20n,so this [after 20n] will only affect simulation or actual digital model to be loaded in form of bit file will be affected ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your first question. Open a new question, please.